# Method compare() removed entries having same value in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, comparator, treemap

I am trying to create a sorted map using `TreeMap<String, Integer>` from an existing map in java.

Entries should be sorted based on value, so I created a custom `Comparator`.

```
class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    Map<String, Integer> base;
    ValueComparator(Map<String, Integer> base) {
        this.base = base;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return base.get(o2).compareTo(base.get(o1));
    }
}

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a", 100);
        map.put("b", 100);
        map.put("c", 200);
        map.put("d", 300);
        map.put("e", 400);
        SortedMap<String, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(new ValueComparator(map));
        sortedMap.putAll(map);
        System.out.println(map);
        System.out.println(sortedMap);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
{a=100, b=100, c=200, d=300, e=400}
{e=400, d=300, c=200, a=100}
```

As you can see, my `sortedMap` has removed one key having the same value. Can someone explain this? And how can we fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the `Comparator` you've provided, Strings `"a"` and `"b"` are duplicates because both of them are associated with value of `100`. Hence, one or the other has to be rejected.

**Note** that `base.get(o2).compareTo(base.get(o1))` would raise a `NullPointerException` if either `o1` or `o2` are not present in the `base` map.

Something along these lines would be safer:

```
Objects.compare(
    base.get(o2), base.get(o1), 
    Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the ordinal for dupes. Use it like this:

```
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    int val = base.get(o2).compareTo(base.get(o1));
    return val == 0 ? o1.compareTo(o2) : val;
}
```

Comment: With after adding above logic, System.out.println(sortedMap.get("a")) gives me null